# Linking a C++ application againt a dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

Can a c++ application be linked against a dll library with Visual Studio?

I have seen some forums which say that it was not the case.

Comment: You would like to link an application to a library, and not vice versa, the regular way?

Comment: yes exactly that 's it: Linking  my dll to the application because I am having actually an error which looks like : Error 16 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl xxx referenced in function "public: void __thiscall xxxid)" (?xxx@xxx@@QAEXXZ) C:\Users\xxx.obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per msdn documentation:

> On the Application Settings page, under Application type, select DLL.

Comment: The problem is resolved, but now: it says that the TEST.dll (the generated dll file of  the project) is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem!